# Eslint with Prettier. Unable to prevent eslint-config-prettier line-length errors

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier

**See Edits at bottom**

I have a JavaScript file that I am linting with Eslint. I am using Prettier to format the code.

My personal choice on this file is to increase the line-length beyond the 80 chars that Prettier has as a default to 2000 chars.

So I have a prettierrc.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  printWidth: 2000
};
```

Which works when I format the code, and I have a .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base",
    "eslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "eslint-plugin-import",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", {}],
    "max-len": ["error", {"code": 2000, "ignoreUrls": true}],
    "linebreak-style": 0,
    "no-use-before-define": ["error", { "functions": false, "classes": false }],
    "no-plusplus": ["error", { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }],
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "import/no-amd": 0,
    "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
  },
  "globals": {
    "define": true
  }
};
```

Everytime I lint the file, it complains about the length of certain lines.

**Edit** for clarity:

I am using **eslint v4.19.1** and **prettier 1.10.2**. Config files are being read and used correctly.

**Edit** for additional information 2018/05/30

I have discovered the distinction in the lint errors. Max-len is working correctly, and the value I have provided as an override in rules is being respected.

What the prettier config has a problem with is the length of some of my conditional expressions. I can see it is wanting to put them on new lines with additional white space. This is now the config I am looking to override. it seems to be a different rule to max-len. The example below is a conditional expression with a length of 60 characters and it is triggering a lint error. The whole line is only 84 characters long (* to represent spaces).

```
**********} else if (firstSessionDate > this.sessionsData[i].SessionStartDateTime) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [ESLint's docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#extending-configuration-files), anything you include in `rules` take precedence over the rules inherited from `extends`, meaning you can change the rule's behavior partially or completely.

That means the `max-len` rule you specified is picked up over the `max-len` rule from `eslint-config-prettier`. You have to delete this rule from your config file and ESLint will stop complaining.

Comment: Hi @Lucas, thank you for coming back to me. I have spent a bit more time on this. The inclusion of max-len is deliberate. That forces eslint to respect my increased line length. Which works, as I have tested and amended the values. if I comment out max-len, I get errors compaining about line-length. What prettier/eslint is actually complaining about is the length of the conditional expressions in some of my if/else statements. It wants to put them on a new line. It took me a while to see the distinction. I am still looking for a way to override this.